# Import the correct Module in Visual Studio - Powershell cmdlets

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, azure-active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     5.1.2      azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureApplicationGatewaySslCertifica...
Script     4.2.1      Azure.Storage                       {Disable-AzureStorageDeleteRetentionPolicy, Enable-AzureSt...
Binary     2.0.1.16   AzureAD                             {Add-AzureADApplicationOwner, Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredO...
Script     4.6.0      AzureRM.Profile                     {Add-AzureRmEnvironment, Clear-AzureRmContext, Clear-Azure...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...
```

In my windows Powershell, I am able to use `Connect-AzureAd` cmdlet.
Now I want to use this in my `C#` application, so I need to import a module that is connected with Connect-AzureAd.

But I listed the modules, I want to import the correct module. Even I worked with all the `.psd1` file my `Connect-AzureAd` command is not recognized.

So, Give me a proper solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: why duplicate, I'm asking about which module

Comment: Why would you use Powershell command from C# instead of the C# SDK ?

Comment: want to run PowerShell cmdlets in C#, using  `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces`;

Comment: You asked how to import a module. You do that with `ImportPSModule`. If you want to find which module provides a command just [check its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0). Or check the contents of the `ExportedCommands` that appears in the results you posted.

Comment: In any case, something called [Connect-AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0) will almost certainly be found in the `AzureAD` module.